# How to resolve Hibernate search [Lucene] OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

- Getting below exception when doing multiple write operations in DB and simulataneously trying to search for the matching word.
- Index file is not updating, confirmed with Luke tool.
- Index file updates only after restarting the server.

Please suggest what changes I have to make.
Thanx in Advance

```
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1075)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:114)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```